# Transitive Relations on a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, binary-operations

I am trying to study binary relations (for myself, it's not an assignment!)
I have the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$,
and one of the relations in the exercise is $\{(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,4)\}$.

A relation is called *transitive* if whenever $(a,b)$ is a member of $R$ and $(b,c)$ is a member of $R$ then $(a,c)$ is also a member of $R$.

Book says it's not a transitive relation. Why?

In given relation we have $(2,3)$, $(3,4)$ and $(2,4)$.  ($x = 2$, $y = 3$, $z = 4$)

Comment: Observe that you have $(2,3)$ and $(3,1)$ but you don't have $(2,1)$. The relation is transitive only if it contains $(x,z)$ *whenever* it contains both $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that you also have (1,3) and (3,1). However you don't have (1,1).

Comment: Of course! Okay, but can you tell me why is this relation transitive ? {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)}

Comment: This is the equality relation of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Equality is of course transitive!

Comment: @Jenkins90 That relation is transitive because whenever it contains $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$, it also contains $(x,z)$.

Comment: They didn't say anything about equality relations in this chapter.. :<. Thanks a lot for your help!